# Solidity: check before withdraw

Tags: solidity

Unfortunately this code doesn't work. It compiles, but the subtraction part doesn't work. Only without the `checkValue` function. Anybody has an idea whats wrong?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;


contract Bank {
    uint private value;
    address private owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function Bank(uint amount) {
        value = amount;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function checkValue(uint amount) returns (bool) {
        return amount >= value;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) {
        value += amount;
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) {
        if(checkValue(amount)) {
        value -= amount;
        }
    }

    function balance() returns (uint) {
        return value;
    }
}

contract MyContract is Bank(10) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't compile. The `value` is not defined anywhere - unless you didn't provide the part where it's defined. Also I assume you'd want `<=` instead of `>=`.

This works:

```
uint value = 50;

function checkValue(uint amount) returns (bool) {
    return amount <= value;
}

function withdraw(uint amount) {
    if(checkValue(amount)) {
        value -= amount;
    }
}
```

You would probably also want to change the `checkValue` function to be a modifier which uses a `require` statement. Something like this:

```
uint value = 50;

modifier checkValue(uint amount) {
    require(amount <= value);
    _;
}


function withdraw(uint amount) checkValue(amount) {
    value -= amount;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing data with value so the contract is just passing numbers around. Also, there is a backwards `amount >= value`. It means the amount to withdraw always has to be more than the amount on deposit. ???

This could be even shorter but I just wanted to illustrate the shift to funds instead of using numbers.

```

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

// A full implementation would include event emitters for each state change. 

contract Bank {

    // uint private value;  // not useful. Just a number, not actual funds.

    address private owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    function Bank() public  {
        // value = amount;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // This function is not needed but included for clarity
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint balancr) {
        return this.balance; 
    }

    // could be fallback (unnamed) function
    function deposit() public payable {
    }

    function withdraw(uint amount) public onlyOwner {
        // Don't even need to check because overdrawing will throw an error. 
        // Including the check for clarity. 
        require(this.balance >= amount);
        owner.transfer(amount);
    }

}
```

```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My toolbar isn't working, so maybe a kind soul will jump in and format that code. :-)

Comment: Thank you, your contract is more realistic and it makes more sense with the require error handling and the unnamed function for deposit, but I am still wondering why my `withdraw` function doesn't work, even if it makes no sense, because it uses just a number and not actual funds

Comment: It's because `amount >= value` should be `amount <= value`.